# Replace part of formula

Tags: vba, excel, replace

my macro is deleting some spreadsheet (let's call it "Base") and replacing it with similar, same name and format, but with different data. There are formulas in other sheets which are refering to "Base" spreadsheet. This formulas, after execution of the macro, return #ADR! error, and formulas are changed, for example:

```
=SUM(Base!AA:AA)
```

becames:

```
=SUM(#ADR!AA:AA)
```

I want to replace "#ADR" with "Base" in every formula, to get rid of this error. One of apporaches which I have been trying is:

```
Selection.Replace What:="#ADR", Replacement:="Base", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

but it doesn't work, even though when I am trying to do it manualy, using Ctrl+h shortcut, everything is perfect.

How can I replace "#ADR!" with "Base" in every selected formula using a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=SUM(INDIRECT("Base!AA:AA"))

INDIRECT takes a string argument, so you will not lose the reference when the sheet is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the sheet you delete that entity. Although you then create a new sheet with the same name it is not the same entity.

So when you delete the sheet, formulas in other sheets referencing it lose that reference. Creating a new sheet with same name will never fix the links.

Would it not be simpler to overwrite the data in the Base sheet, therefore preserving all the links and eliminating the issue entirely?